# Add integer from another class in a textView

Tags: java, android, textview

In the `MainActivity` class I have a `TextView` and I want to have it populated with an **integer** from another class. The integer is the result of some database calculations. How can I set the `TextView` text with the 'sum' integer from the other class? Thank you!

**MainActivity TextView**:

```
valFormula.setText( here I need to pass the sum Integer);
```

And this is the class in which I calculate the sum value:

```
public class CalculateItems extends AppCompatActivity {
        MyDBHandler myDb;
        String timeStamp = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        int sum;

    public void myResult() {
                List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
                myDb = new MyDBHandler(this);
                Cursor cursor = myDb.getItemsToday();
                if (cursor !=null) {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                int timeWhenAdded = cursor.getInt(1);
                                int timePassed = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp) - timeWhenAdded;
                                int price = total - (int) ((percentageToDecrease / 100) * discount);
                                items.add(price);
                        }
                }
                //This is the variable that I want to have it displayed in the textView:
                sum = 0;
                for (int i : items)
                        sum += i;
        }
```

Comment: you want to set text to a TextView in MainActivity from some other Activity

Comment: And what would be the best approach in my case? To have myResults method in another class and be able to call sum in the MainActivity textview?

Comment: i am confuse with your question you want to get sum in your `MainActivity` which is being calculated in some other `Activity`, always remember at a time there is only one Activity Visible(working) if your result activity is invoked from `MainActivity` you need to close it after your logic completes and return your result back to `MainActivity` then you can show result in `MainActivity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you should not update views of another activity. If you need just calculate something create static method

```
public class CalculateItems {
    public static int myResult() {
        int sum = 0;
        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
        MyDBHandler myDb = new MyDBHandler(this);
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getItemsToday();
        if (cursor !=null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int timeWhenAdded = cursor.getInt(1);
                int timePassed = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp) - timeWhenAdded;
                int price = total - (int) ((percentageToDecrease / 100) * discount);
                items.add(price);
            }
        }
        for (int i : items)
            sum += i;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and call it from main activity when you need it

```
valFormula.setText(CalculateItems.myResult());
```